# Can't load weights of a keras model saved with old keras version using new keras version

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tf.keras

I'm trying to set weights of a keras model (loaded with new keras version - 2.2.4-tf, which is now under tensorflow package) which was saved to a DB using old keras, but it is failing with the error:

```
ValueError: Layer weight shape (8,) not compatible with provided weight shape (1, 9, 8, 4)
```

Here is a code snippet depicting what we were trying to do:

```
model = keras.models.model_from_json(...)
model.compile(...)
model.set_weights(...)
```

As stated before, the code is crashing in the model.set_weights(...) function, producing the above error.

We found out that the same layers exist both in the model loaded using an old keras version (2.3.1) - which also succeeded to set the weights properly - and also with the model loaded using new keras version (2.2.4-tf), **but not in the same order**.

Below is the output of the code:

`collection.Counter([ww.shape for ww in m_old.get_weights()])`

and the code:

`collection.Counter([ww.shape for ww in m_new.get_weights()])`

where m_old is the model loaded by the old keras version and the m_new is the model loaded by the new keras version:

```
Out[20]:
Counter({(7, 1, 1, 8): 5,
         (8,): 20,
         (1, 9, 8, 4): 5,
         (4,): 20,
         (120, 1): 5,
         (1,): 5})
Out[21]:
Counter({(7, 1, 1, 8): 5,
         (8,): 20,
         (1, 9, 8, 4): 5,
         (4,): 20,
         (120, 1): 5,
         (1,): 5})
```

We will appreciate any help.

Comment: It looks like the issue is between your second and third layer (in the counter output) - you might want to check the documentation to see the changes made to either of those two layers between the two tensorflow versions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Can you please tell me how did you understand that the problem is between the second and third layer from the counters?

Comment: The error says shape (8,) not compatible with ( 1, 9, 8 ,4) i.e. the shape of the second and third parts of the counter object. It's just a guess because I can't see the actual layer types, but at some point between those two layers the shapes don't match. Check the output shape of the (8,) layer and the input shape of the next for the two tensorflow versions and see if there's a difference

Comment: Can you provide model architecture to debug the code. Thanks!